# How can I estimate the size of the model with a distillBERT layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to get the size of the DistillBERT model trained on the ENRON dataset.
I believe that I can get an approximation for the size of the model based on the number of parameters at each layer, its weights, and biases. But what is the way to get it? How can I calculate the size of the model?

Below I have describes the model in detail along with the code.

Here is my model:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import transformers
from transformers import DistilBertTokenizer
from transformers import TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
MODEL_NAME = 'distilbert-base-uncased'

# loading the data and processing it.
df = pd.read_csv("enron6dataset.csv", error_bad_lines=False)
train_df = df.sample(frac=0.8, random_state=25)
test_df = df.drop(train_df.index)
X_train = train_df.email
X_test = test_df.email
y_train = train_df.label
y_test = test_df.label

y_train_encoded = tf.one_hot(y_train.values, 2)
y_test_encoded = tf.one_hot(y_test.values, 2)

# tokenization and model compilation

tokenizer = DistilBertTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME)

train_encodings = tokenizer(list(X_train.values),
                            truncation=True, 
                            padding=True)
test_encodings = tokenizer(list(X_test.values),
                           truncation=True, 
                           padding=True)

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(train_encodings),list(y_train_encoded )))

test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(test_encodings),list(y_test_encoded )))
test_dataset2 = test_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).take(1000).batch(16)

model = TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME)

optimizerr = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=5e-5)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizerr,
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# fine tuning the model
model.fit(train_dataset.shuffle(len(X_train)).batch(16),
          epochs=2,
          batch_size=16,callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
#accuracy
results = model.evaluate(test_dataset2)
print("test loss, test acc:", results)
```

I am getting following accuracy -

```
63/63 [==============================] - 2s 32ms/step - loss: 0.0135 - accuracy: 0.9950
test loss, test acc: [0.01349691767245531, 0.9950000047683716]
```

`model.summary()` gives the following result -

```
Model: "tf_distil_bert_for_sequence_classification"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
distilbert (TFDistilBertMain multiple                  66362880  
_________________________________________________________________
pre_classifier (Dense)       multiple                  590592    
_________________________________________________________________
classifier (Dense)           multiple                  1538      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_19 (Dropout)         multiple                  0         
=================================================================
Total params: 66,955,010
Trainable params: 66,955,010
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Firstly why is it showing `multiple` in the output shape?

the following are the layers of the model - `model.layers` :

```
[<transformers.models.distilbert.modeling_tf_distilbert.TFDistilBertMainLayer at 0x2b268cbbfb20>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense at 0x2b268cbdd670>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense at 0x2b268cbddfa0>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dropout at 0x2b268cbdf730>]
```

Comment: Can you add all your imports to your question?

Comment: @AloneTogether I have added all the imports Please check. And if you can give me ideas or resources on how to calculate the memory requirement of the model based on the parameters, weights and biases, it would be a great help. Thank you